# Ionic Webview data parsing

Tags: ionic-framework, webview, cordova-plugins

I have a doubt in Ionic webview.

For example: if am creating an app like paytm, then after clicking 'proceed to pay' button, it'll redirect to the webview of some payment gateways --> after that the gateway gives a response, which we get in our app.

Here, while redirect to the gateway webview what kind of parameters to be send and what kind of responses we can get back from the webview.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you get the solution for it?

Answer (score 1):

You can send a thing like a cart unique id to the webview via get params.

Example : http://www.example.com/cart?id=1234

And you can get something, like payment ok with a specific url

http://www.example.com/cart/success

And track that url to get out of the gateway.

Comment: The webview is purely dependent on the web right? we cannot do anything with that!                                                                                     (i.e) I can send a particular id or username ==> and the webview gets it and processes it, and send backs me a data that everything is okay or not okay!            Thats it! i cannot mess with that webview right? like handling sessions something like that?

Comment: Yes it is dependent of the web. Handling session would be difficult.